# Regarding android device reservation status

Tags: android, adb

I have one query regarding android device reservation status, can someone help me out in resolving this.

Lets say i have one device connected to my laptop and i am currently executing some automation script on that device.
If i open another terminal/command prompt and tries to execute another automation script of the same device.

Is there any possibility to shown android device status when tries to access the same device from another terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of script? is it an application (apk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play around with `adb shell ps | grep ^shell` to get the list of all the processes running from shell:

```
shell     210   1     5712   344   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell     12961 210   2412   716   00000000 b6f95ffc R ps
```

here is the minimal output since `adb` and `ps` are running in order to get this work. well, you can consider other activity as connected to this device terminals